# User defined variable as a filename in a CSV Data Set Config element

Tags: jmeter

I have a user defined variable that I put the location to a csv file.

csv_path = mydrive/thisfolder/thecsv.csv

When I put ${csv_path} as my filename argument in the CSV Data Set Config element I get an error and it shows up that the path is only the name of the csv file.  If I manually put the filename in there it works.  Any ideas?  I am trying to create a relative path to it rather than hardcoding an absolute path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you define the user defined variables, assign the path of the csv file (relative paths work) using a property like shown below:

[image]

And then, in your CSV Data Set Config, refer that file using the property name like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

CSV Data Set Config element is initialized **before** any JMeter Variables so consider using a JMeter Property instead. JMeter Properties is an instance of [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) hence inherit all the features like:

- Properties are global for the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) and once defined live until JVM is shut down
- As a consequence of previous point - you can use JMeter Properties to share data across Thread Groups while JMeter Variables are local to their own Thread Group and cannot be accessed outside
- You can specify a default value so i.e. if property is not overrided - the reasonable default is being used instead

So in order to parametrize your CSV file name:

1. Define a JMeter property. There are 2 main ways:

   - Add the following line to *user.properties* file (lives in JMeter's "bin" folder)

     ```
     csv_path = mydrive/thisfolder/thecsv.csv
     ```
   - Pass the property to JMeter via `-J` command-line argument like:

     ```
     jmeter -Jcsv_path = mydrive/thisfolder/thecsv.csv -n -t ....
     ```

     See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on different JMeter and Java properties types and ways of working with them
2. Once you defined the property you can access it's value where required using [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) or [__property()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) function like:

   - `${__P(csv_path,)}`
   - `${__property(csv_path,,)}`

It's better to develop functions using [Functions Helper Dialog](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) as their syntax might seem scary.