# Pass a property to CSV Data Set Config filename input

Tags: jmeter

In a `JSR223 PreProcessor` I define two properties:

```
props.put("DATAFILE_PATH", "pathtofile");
props.put("ENV", "env_test");
```

Then in `CSV Data Set Config` object I use:

```
Filename : props.get("DATAFILE_PATH")
File encoding : UTF-8
...
```

However, I'm facing this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File props.get("DATAFILE_PATH") must exist and be readable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CSV Data Set Config` is [Configuration element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) which is executed before pre processors (or other element)

> Execution order
>
> 0.Configuration elements
>
> 1.Pre-Processors

So you can't update this property using pre processor, only by defining such property before execution as [different answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38622888/user-defined-variable-as-a-filename-in-a-csv-data-set-config-element) suggesting, using user defined variables or adding property to execution